# The command line for 'atprogram' does not work properly in WPF

Tags: wpf, atmel

I am building a WPF application that can flash Atmel MCU. I am using 'atprogram' command line to flash the MCU. Below is the code snippets.

```cs
using (Process sortProcess = new Process())
{
    sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + @"\Atmel\Studio\7.0\atbackend\atprogram";
    string hexFileName = "PROGRAM.hex";
    string arguments = FormattableString.Invariant($"/K \"{path}\" -t atmelice -i ISP -d atmega328pb program -f \"{hexFileName}\" --verify");
    sortProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    sortProcess.Start();
}
```

When I run the application, the command lines show:

```sh
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch files.
```

When I removed '*\"{hexFileName}\"*' from the program **AND** also tried to copy and paste the arguments (with double quotes) on Command Prompt, the program works fine (even it gives error). May I know what is the problem?

Comment: trying to modify the code @"\Atmel\Studio\7.0\atbackend\atprogram.exe" . good luck

Comment: Hi, I have tried with .exe. But, I still get the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to do this code

```
        using (Process sortProcess = new Process())
        {
            sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + @"\Atmel\Studio\7.0\atbackend\atprogram.exe";
            string hexFileName = "PROGRAM.hex";
            string arguments = FormattableString.Invariant($" -t atmelice -i ISP -d atmega328pb program -f \"{hexFileName}\" --verify");
            sortProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            sortProcess.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Byoung Sam Moon, sorry for late reply. My program is working. Thank you very much.